# Disable iPhone location prompts

Tags: iphone, ios, geolocation

For my work, I have to use an application that needs "Always On" location on my iPhone (latest iOS 13), but every day (sometimes twice a day) I have the "X is tracking your location." prompt. I answer "Always on" every time, but every day they ask me again...

Is there a way to see these pop-ups less often, or to completely deactivate them ?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there’s no “don’t ask me again” option. iOS 13 will keep asking you about the apps using your location in the background unless you tap “Change to Only While Using.” iOS won’t warn you about apps that can only access your location while you’re using them.